# Union with Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine, union

I need to create a QueryBuilder with union, is that possible ?

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
   ->select('table1.numObject AS id')
   ->select ('table1.name AS name')
   ->from("MyBundle:Table1", "table1")
```

and
   union

```
   ->select('table2.id AS id')
   ->select ('table2.name AS name')
   ->from("MyBundle:Table2", "table2")
```

Note : it has to be a queryBuilder object (not query or something else)

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately `UNION` is not possible within `Doctrine`. You have to fetch two sets from database and do "union" manually on php side or use native sql.

Check [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5657) for more information

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible via the `Doctrine` syntax, but it is possible using plain SQL and a statement:

```
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT numObject AS id, name FROM table1

UNION // or UNION ALL if you want duplicates

SELECT id, name FROM table2
SQL;

    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (DBALException $e) {
        return [];
    }
```

This will give you either an array with the rows you requested or an empty array in case of an error.

Comment: do you have links to any documentation regarding the `<<<SQL` syntax?

Comment: @JoelLau https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 1):

As [Tomaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393077/tomasz-madeyski) answered above, it's not possible to create a `UNION` using the `createQueryBuilder` function but we can achieve it by using `createNativeQuery`. Please check the below example,

```
public function firstQuery(array $filters) {
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('table1.numObject AS id, table1.name AS name')
            ->from("MyBundle:Table1", "table1");

    return $qb->getQuery();
}

public function secondQuery(array $filters) {
    $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('table2.numObject AS id, table2.name AS name')
            ->from("MyBundle:Table2", "table2");

    return $qb->getQuery();
}

// Main function
public function getAPIResult(array $filters, int $pageSize, int $page) {
    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->em);

    $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id', 'integer');
    $rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'name', 'string');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM (
         ({$this->firstQuery($filters)->getSQL()})
         UNION ALL
         ({$this->secondQuery($filters)->getSQL()})
     ) tmp 
    ORDER BY name
    LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
    ";
    $query = $this->em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    $this->em->setParameter(1, $pageSize)
       ->setParameter(2, $pageSize * ($page-1));

    return $query->getScalarResult();
}
```

Check official docs for Scalar Result:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results

**Note:** The above code snippet is not tested, please put a comment if face any issues.

Hope it helps. Happy coding ;)

Comment: This solution will not work if your queries have parameters, because `getSQL` method returns prepared query with `?` placeholders instead parameters (even if you use named ones) and mapping logic is in `Query::execute` method

Comment: Yes @BoShurik, You're correct but it was just an example if you have one or more parameters inside the `firstQuery` or `secondQuery`, you would need to set the parameters after creating the native query using the `createNativeQuery` but with the correct parameter index numbers.